# Even using an ErrorInterceptor should I still "catch/handle" the error on the observable.subscribe?

Tags: angular

I've adapted this ErrorInterceptor from statckoverflow and it got me thinking.
I'm used to get observable data applying the success and the error handler (when need it).

- So I wondered, since I got an ErrorInterceptor, I still have to catch the error on the getRequest?
- Will my application crash even if the error is got on the interceptor, but not on the observable.subscribe?
  This is my Interceptor:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>{

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            tap(resp => {
                if(resp instanceof HttpResponse){
                    //logic for a LOG
                }
            }),
            catchError((resp: HttpErrorResponse) => {

                if (resp.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
                    //client-side error
                    //logic for a LOG
                } else {
                    //server-side error
                    //logic for a LOG
                }

                return throwError(() => resp.error);
            }),
            finalize(() => {
                //logic for a LOG
            })
        );
    }
```

And this dummy getRequest to ilustrate:

```
getSomeData(): Observable<any>{
    const url = 'some/api/endpoint';
    return this.http.get(url);
}

getMyData(){
    this.getSomeData().subscribe({
        next: (data: any) => console.log(data)
    });
}
```

Note that getMyData() do not address the error handler.So I wanted to know if it's ok to leave the code like this.
I wonder that if an error occurred it would be caught by the Interceptor and the application would continue normally. Like a standard Try/Catch block.
Am I wrong to assume that?
I wouldn't want to do this:

```
    getMyData(){
            this.getSomeData().subscribe({
                next: (data: any) => console.log(data),
                error: err => //do same and repetitive error logic for every observable
            });
        }
```

Comment: I can be wrong here but i think the whole purpose of catching an error is to log it and properly know what it is. It doesn't make the error magically disapear !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll still want to handle the error where you’ve subscribed to the http observable. Like the comment above, the interceptor doesn’t magically make the error go away, it just gives you a means to capture or handle errors generally. Saving you from creating an abstracted http service to add in extra error handling logic around http requests..

The two examples of where I’ve an error interceptor were:

1. Logging errors
2. Catching when an expired auth token was sent, making a refresh token call and then retrying the request.

Answer (score -1):

considering that you are going to debug, I should have more information about the code, but I think I know where the problem is. If you allow me, I will first tell you the correct type of error handling in the interceptor itself, and after that, I will tell you an example of error handling in the method you want. In the second case, I guess that you either had a problem defining the interceptor or that you did not import it correctly in the provider ==>

**The first example of error handling in the interceptor itself:**

```
**auth.interceptor.ts**


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpErrorResponse,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()

export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private url;
  private prefixReq;
  private serversUrl = {
    gameprofile: 'http://gameprofile.iconish.ir',
    engine: 'http://qmiuengine.iconish.ir'
  };

  private currentUser: UserInterface;

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private userStoreService: UserStoreService) {
  }


  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let copyReq;
    this.prefixReq = request.url.split('/')[0];
    this.url = this.serversUrl[this.prefixReq];
    if (!request.url.startsWith('.') && !request.url.startsWith('custom')) {
//do somthing

      copyReq = request.clone({
        url: `${this.url}${request.url.replace(this.prefixReq, '')}`
      });

    } else {
      this.url = request.url.replace('custom/', '');
      copyReq = request.clone({
        url: `${this.url}`
      });
    }
    return next.handle(copyReq).pipe(
      tap(evt => {
        if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
//do somthing
        }
      }),
      catchError((err: any) => {
        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          try {
            if (err.error === 'Unauthorized') {
              this.userStoreService.removeUserAccount();
              this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
            }
          } catch (e) {
            console.log('An error occurred', e);
          }
        }
        return of(err);
      }));
  }
}
```

**The second example:**

```
**auth.interceptor.ts**


import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError} from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class ErrorCatchingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor() {
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
        return next.handle(request)
            .pipe(
                catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    let errorMsg = '';
                    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
                        console.log('This is client side error');
                        errorMsg = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
                    } else {
                        console.log('This is server side error');
                        errorMsg = `Error Code: ${error.status},  Message: ${error.message}`;
                    }
                    console.log(errorMsg);
                    return throwError(errorMsg);
                })
            )
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: ErrorCatchingInterceptor,
            multi: true
        }
    ],
    ...
})
export class AppModule {
}
```